# IIS server loading old files?

Tags: iis, iis-6, c#

I have installed IIS server 6.0, and also deployed my website on it.
Although I have made certain changes in code, **the server still loads the old versions of the files**.

Changes made in the designer page are reflecting, but `.cs` pages are not.

Comment: Have you replaced the modified DLL's after Changing the code in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the IIS server using `iisReset`

Try clearing following folder `bootdrive:\%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.5 0727\Temporary ASP.NET Files`